# Programatically make direct query with "AND", "OR", "NOT" on search API Solr Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I am new to Drupal. I'm trying to implement advanced search on my Drupal8 website. It's working perfectly with the logical operator `OR` and `AND` but not with `NOT`, `+`, `-`.

Here is my request :

```
$index = \Drupal\search_api\Entity\Index::load('videos_full');
    $query = $index->query();
    $parse_mode = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.search_api.parse_mode')
                  ->createInstance('direct');
    $query->setParseMode($parse_mode);
    $query->addCondition('search_api_language', \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId());
    $query->addCondition("status",5);

    $query->setFulltextFields(['field_title', 'title', 'resourcetype', 'tag', 'choreographer', 'director', 'producer', 'structure', 'contributor', 'secondaryauthor']);
    $query->keys($search);

    $query->sort('created','DESC');
    $results = $query->execute();
```

For example if i'm typing "iggy NOT pop", I have a lot of result with "iggy pop"

Thank you for your help !

Comment: When you say not working you mean it returns nothing ? or wrong results ? ..

Comment: For example if i'm typing "iggy NOT pop", I have a lot of result with "iggy pop" .

Comment: Can you please update your post with this information it will help people react faster to your question

Comment: Ok thank you, it's done

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and I can't confirm

> It's working perfectly with the logical operator OR and AND

When entering

> iggy OR pop

it performs an "AND"-search, results do not include content with just "iggy" or just "pop". Are u sure operators can be set like this?

I read something about

```
$parse_mode = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.search_api.parse_mode')
  ->createInstance('direct');
$parse_mode->setConjunction('OR');
$query->setParseMode($parse_mode);
```

in the docs but this doesn't seem to work, too. "iggy pop" and "iggy OR pop" do not find content with just "iggy", it's like the "AND" is forced.

The only way I got to work the operators is by giving an array to the query instead of a string:

```
$search_string_exploded = str_word_count($search_string, 1);
$keys = array_merge($search_string_exploded, ['#conjunction' => 'OR']);
$query->keys($keys);
```

Maybe this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The search query string in drupal is sanitized, and that's probably why you won't be able to use solr's +/-

What I would do is customize the query sanitization in Drupal, to just allow for + and -.
The solr's - operator is the only way to achieve the NOT functionality.

Hope this helps.